# is console.log(i) inside a loop counts as operation in big O

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I'm trying to understand Big O notation but i don't know if i have the following code:

```
function(n){
    for(let i = 0; i <n i++){
         console.log(i);
    }
}
```

is console.log(i) we consider it as an operation when we count or not 
so it's an O(n) inside a loop which is also O(n) so this function is O(n^2)

Comment: Sure, it's an operation, but what makes you think that it's specifically an O(n) operation?

Comment: @sepp2k because it will output as much as the n value

Comment: `console.log(42)` will output two characters, not 42. So it doesn't output as much as the value of `i`, but the *length* of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(i)` is just outputting a single number, not (for instance) every number up to the specified "i". So that single command is just O(1).

For an "n" that is three times as high, the whole loop needs to do three times as much work, not 3² times as much, so this function is O(n).

Comment: Outputting a 10-digit number will take about 10 times as much time as printing a single-digit number, won't it? So it's not O(1) (unless we consider the fact that there's an upper bound to how large a number can be in JavaScript, in which case the entire function would become O(1), but that's clearly not helpful).